# nginx with passenger don't handle static assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I have rails app running with helpfull nginx and passenger, and I want to add static page (conteins code coverage analysis tool - simplecov).
Localy this works fine (without passenger), but on the server this don't works.
My nginx.conf:

```
    #user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
    #speed up for linux 2.6+
    use epoll;
}


http {

    passenger_root /home/demo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@gm/gems/passenger-3.0.9;
    passenger_ruby /home/demo/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p0@gm/ruby;

    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
       listen 80;
       server_name *.dev.mysite.com;
       root /var/www/projects/mysite/qa/current/public;
       passenger_enabled on;

       rails_env qa;

       charset utf-8;
       error_log  /var/www/projects/mysite/qa/shared/log/host.error.log;
    }

    #Coverage code tool (SimpleCov gem)
    server {
       listen 4444;
           server_name coverage.mysite.com;
       location / {
           root /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/WebForms/workspace/coverage;
           index index.html index.htm;
       }
    }

    #Yard server
    server {
       listen 5555;
       server_name yard.mysite.com;
       location / {
         proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8808;
       }}}
```

And nothing receive when I try to hit to coverage.mysite.com:4444.

Answer (score 2):

I think I remember coming across something similar to this on one of my rails apps.

Have you tried commenting and uncommenting the lines below?:

```
# in config/environments/production.rb

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files
  #config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile"

  # For nginx:
  config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect'
```

It should be near the top, around line 12 through 16.

Try that, then redploy and test in the browser.